# Passing images from Node.js to Jade to be displayed in a table-row

Tags: node.js, image, express, pug, render

I try to passing an array of objects form Node.js to Jade to be displayed as a table. This works so far.
How do I have to code it, when in one column an image should be displayed?
In dataarray I have the database documents as an array of objects.
I have the bild all the images which correspond to the dataarray

The image itself is rendered when I code it as follows (see below)
However when I try to render it as part of the table it fails.

Node.js

```
res.render('index', {
    title: 'Image Analysis - this is the content of the database',
       src: bild[0].toString('base64'),
      dbdoc: dataarray
  });
```

Index.jade

```
img(with=50 height=50 alt='Wikipedia', src='data:img/png;base64,#{src}')

  table(border='1')
    thead
        tr
            th #
            th Image Id
            th processed
            th RasPi Location
            th Celebrity
            th Age
            th Gender
            th Additional fields
    tbody        
            each val in dbdoc
              tr
                td= 1
                td= val.ImageID
                td= val.entryprocessed       
                td= val.raspilocation
                td= val.celebrity
                td= val.age
                td= val.gender
                td= val.addfield
```

Comment: Can you add the code that is failing?

Comment: I am able to do this.....please see [my question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42777077/passing-array-of-image-objects-to-the-jade-and-then-displaying-via-jade)