# passing array of image objects to the jade and then displaying via jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, express, pug

Here, I have use.js and use.jade.

In use.js, I am simply mapping hardcoded image variable `img_01` from jade to use.js by specifying `var $image= $(pclass + 'img_01');`

In .js, I am assigning $image by some useful image using 
   `$image.attr('src', useful_image)` 
Using `img.use--img_01` in .jade, I am able to display the image (useful_image).
Now, my constraint is I don't want to hard code in .jade and let .jade display images as many as provided by .js.

So, I am able to create the array in .js of `var $image=[]` and then `$image.push($(pclass + 'img_' + N.toString())` where N varies from 0 to K (lets say K =3).

Now I want to call these `img_0, img_1, img_2 .....img_K` in .jade and display them on page.

So my specific question is I am not able to iterate `[img_0, img_1, img_2 .....img_K]` in .jade. Can anyone tell what could be best method to do so????

**Pls note:** I used rendering method. For the same I used

`var express = require('express');
 var app = express();`

But, node.js gets crashed with this itself leave aside using app.get...

Comment: Please format blocks of code using the code formatting button `{}`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

You can pass object from server to client in this way.

```
 app.get(..., function (req, res) {
        var stats = { ... };
        res.render('chart', { images: $arrImage });
     });
```

For looping at client  ,you can use [`jade#each`](https://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/).

```
each oneImage in images
 img( src=oneImage.image)
```

Note : Jade is depricated,So try to use [`Pug#each`](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html)

Comment: it does not allow to create  app via express in use.js....so no question of using app.get

Comment: Please tag use.js the n

Comment: How you rendering view?

Comment: `h2.base--h2.use--output-header Game One
    .use--output-line
      #box.boxes
      .use--output-data
      .use--output-image-place
        img.use--img_0`

Comment: Can u please share the script where you calling html to render